# expected class-name before ‘{’ token {

Tags: c++

I have a very simple program, two classes, inheritance, and I can't work out why it isn't working. It's getting on my nerves.

I have in main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "square.h"

class shapeparent
{
    protected:
        int width;
        int height;
    public:

        void setvalues(int a, int b)
        {
            width = a;
            height = b;
        }

};

int main()
{
    square small;

    small.setvalues(5,5);

    small.printarea();

    // return 0;

}
```

And then in square.h

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H

class square: public shapeparent
{
    public:
            void printarea()
        {
            // std::cout << width << std::endl;
            // std::cout << height << std::endl;
            int area = width*height;
            std::cout << area << std::endl;
        }


};

#endif
```

I get the error 'expected class-name before ‘{’ token' in square.h

Comment: You cannot inherit from a class that hasn't yet been declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class shareparent shall be defined before class square. Any name used in C+ program shall be at first defined before its using.

I advice to place the definition of class shapeparent in a separate header file for example `"shareparent.h"` and include this header in file `square.h`. For example

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H

#include "shareparent.h"

class square: public shapeparent

//...
```

Comment: Any name used in a C++ shall be declared before its use (except in dependent contexts in templates).  Only certain used require a complete definition.  (Of course, using the name as a base class is one that does require the complete definition.  And the OP didn't even provide a declaration.)

Comment: @James Kanze  I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

So as Nightfold and Vlad from Moscow indicate, the `shapeparent` class must be declared before the `square` class that derives from it:

```
class shapeparent
{
...
};

class square : public shapeparent
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error means, that the "shapeparent" is an unknown symbol, as the square is included before the shapepepernt is specified.

The most common solution would be to put the shapeparent class into separate file and include it from the square.h

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would be to create another file `shapeparent.h` which contains the `shapeparent` class. Remember to get your include guards set up correctly (`#ifndef SHAPEPARENT_H` etc).

Then edit `shape.h` to have `#include "shape.h"` *before* the class declaration. This will fix the error.

In `main.cpp`, include both `shape.h` and `shapeparent.h`.

Answer (score 1):

class shapeparent must be defined before declaring square.
Have square.h as below:

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H
class shapeparent
{
    protected:
        int width;
        int height;
    public:

        void setvalues(int a, int b)
        {
            width = a;
            height = b;
        }

};
class square: public shapeparent
{
    public:
            void printarea()
        {
            // std::cout << width << std::endl;
            // std::cout << height << std::endl;
            int area = width*height;
            std::cout << area << std::endl;
        }


};

#endif
```